# How to identify Microsoft Word Elements

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010, adobe-acrobat, rtf

I have used Acrobat PRO to convert a PDF file to a Microsoft Word .docx file. The Word document contains a few tables. In the last row of the table, are two shadowed boxes. I am attaching a .jpg as an example.

[image]

This appears to be data in the last row of the table. I have read both an xml and rtf version of the Word document, but do not fully understand the structure. I have never created this type of element in Word before, and do not know what it is.

In other words, I am having difficulty figuring out what kind of Word elements these boxes are. As silly as it may sound, I would like to make one of the box's outlines the same size as the other. I'm more than willing to edit the .rtf or .xml, but would like to know where a guide is, so I can make sense of what I am reading. Or, should I be re-creating these in something like MSPaint?

Here is the options menu after right mouse clicking on one of the boxes:

[image]

Comment: Are they nested individual tables or cells? What have you attempted so far? Have you tried simply recreating them?

Comment: I do not believe the table is nested. I believe this data exists in the last row. I edited the OP in response to your questions.

Comment: Plain text box perhaps? If you select them and right-click what options do you see?

Comment: The options picture is small, but it starts out with Cut, Copy, and Paste Options.